# Error Occurs with memcpy

Tags: c

I tried to use memcpy() function but a error occur:

```
typedef struct
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    }A;

void Test(void **obj)
{
    A *object=(A*)malloc(sizeof(A));

    memcpy(object,*obj,sizeof(A));//program crash here
    printf("a=%d\n",object->a);
    printf("b=%d\n",object->b);
    free(*obj);
    *obj=NULL;

}
void main()
{
    A *obj=(A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
    obj->a=1;
    obj->b=2;
    Test((void**)obj);

}
```

The notification show: **"Access violation reading location 0x00000001"**
When I pass the argument is void* obj. There is not any problem
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You have used a typecast to mask a bug in your code. You need to change:

```
Test((void**)obj);
```

to:

```
Test(&obj);
```

Take-home message: whenever you feel that you need to use a typecast ask yourself why - in the majority of cases it's the wrong solution and will just obscure more serious problems.

Note: you should probably also change:

```
void Test(void **obj)
```

to:

```
void Test(A **obj)
```

since there is no good reason to use `void **` here.

Comment: Thanks Paul R for your quick answer. But when I use your way,there is a new error: Error "cannot convert parameter 1 from A ** to void ** "  and I change to  (Test((void**)&obj) )     It runs ok.

Comment: It would be better to fix the function `Test` as mentioned above, i.e. change `void Test(void **obj)` to `void Test(A **obj)`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't pass the address of the pointer to the function, you pass the pointer itself so `*obj` in the function is the same as `*obj` in the `main` function.

Use the address-of operator to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
Test(&obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is still not compiled but when I change to Test((void**)&obj). It is ok. The compile may not cast &obj to (void**) automatically

Comment: @NgọcTânĐỗ A `void` pointer can point to _anything_, which is why you never need to cast to `void *`, only the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

```
void main()
{
    A *obj=(A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
    obj->a=1;
    obj->b=2;
    Test((void**)obj); //here is the problem

}
```

you are not passing the address of *obj, you are just casting the (A *) to (void * **),void

```
main()
{
    A *obj=(A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
    obj->a=1;
    obj->b=2;
    Test(&obj);

}
```

Memory leak in Test function, 'object' is malloced but not freed neither returned.